# Android encrypted file to store the game score

Tags: android

I'm developing a game where I need to store the current score to add new points if the user win a match.
Looking the google game sample I found this comment:

```
   public void saveLocal(Context ctx) {
        /* TODO: This is left as an exercise. To make it more difficult to cheat,
         * this data should be stored in an encrypted file! And remember not to
         * expose your encryption key (obfuscate it by building it from bits and
         * pieces and/or XORing with another string, for instance). */
    }
```

They are storing the points in a local score, then they add the points to this local variable to upload the new score on the leaderboard.

Any example to implement this feature?
Is there another better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with point-based games is that you have to save the score somewhere where your app can access it. As a result tech-savvy users could try to reverse-engineer your game and thus modify their score.
The easiest way to prevent users from doing so is saving the score in the storage private to your app (hence in the preferences or /app/data/yourpackage - just don't reference this path, use getFilesDir()). This however won't stop users on rooted phones as they can access those files.
Next step is to serialize this score in a file using some arbitrary data-format (maybe using standard java Serializable) - your users won't be able to read the file anymore. To modify the score they'd need knowledge of developing in Android (decompiling & deserialization)
To increase security even more you can encrypt this file after it has been serialized (or even better - Encrypt the stream you serialize your score with). Refer to [here](http://www.codejava.net/coding/file-encryption-and-decryption-simple-example) on how to encrypt files. Store the key needed for encryption / decryption in your code.

Because the key is stored in your code it can be read after decompiling your app. There is no way around it except making it harder to obtain (security trough obscurity). You can achieve that by obfuscating your code and splitting the encryption key in multiple parts which you scatter throughout your project.

Just be aware that there is no perfect way to hinder your users from cheating - you can just lay stones in the way.

**Side node: Export of Encryption is regulated in the USA - this affects you if you plan on publishing your app trough Google play as your app is hosted in the USA**

Start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Export_of_cryptography_from_the_United_States) to read more on that.

Comment: The library itself looks pretty good. I'd still not store the exact value of the score but something like a complementary value (done with ~VARIABLE in java). Remember to check on the export laws regarding encryption.

Comment: But I have a new problem, if the user press "delete data from this app" bye bye my local storage

Comment: You could store the file on the external storage or on a server. Both ways impose their own risk (especially when saving on a server). But if a user wants to delete the app's data you can't prevent it.